# How can I remove dirt that has blown into my landscaping rock?

Tags: landscaping

We have an empty field by our house that is being made into a subdivision, and now that they have started work on it the wind has blown 6 to 8 inches of dirt in certain spots in among the rock in my front yard.  I'm looking for any ideas on how to get it all out.

Comment: Do you mean there's an 8" layer of dirt in your yard? or the dirt has trickled down 8" into rocks?

Answer (score 2):

If you have that much dirt blown into your yard, I'm also gussing your porch, windows, sills, and any other surfaces are also dirty.

Just hit with a hose, as you wash everthing else.  The dirt will make it's way thorugh the gaps in the rocks and wash out.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good results with a similar problem using a leaf blower - blow it back at them!